# Android 11 - window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows applies for both - status and navigation

Tags: android-statusbar, android-11, translucentdecor

With old-fashioned flags we could create an app with translucent param applied only to a status bar.

```
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = window.decorView.systemUiVisibility or 
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
```

But in a new api `window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)` applies translucent for both - status bar and navigation bar. So, the new api provides less functionality or I'm missing something?

Comment: You can still use an opaque color for the navigation bar by setting such a color for the navigation bar with: `<item name="android:navigationBarColor">NON_TRANLUCENT_COLOR</item>`

Comment: So you mean that with setDecorFitsSystemWindows() and android:navigationBarColor=NON_TRANLUCENT_COLOR simultaneously my window will not stretch under android navigation bar?